# Screen resolution on Nexus 4 and Nexus 7

Tags: nexus-7, nexus-4, screen-resolution

If I understand [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/25252/9841) answer correctly, then the Nexus 7 (7" screen at 1280x800) should show more of a given webpage (or of anything else) than the Nexus 4 (4.7" screen at 1280x768). This means that a Nexus 7 will not simply look like an enlarged Nexus 4? It will appear to have a higher resolution, because of the "dp" value mentioned in that post?

I have a handset similar to the Nexus 4 and am considering a Nexus 7. However, if the Nexus 7 will appear as a larger version of my current handset (that is, what I see on screen at the moment will still appear on a full screen on the Nexus 7), then the purchase may not be worth it.

Comment: The Nexus 4 has a 4.7 inch 1280*768 screen, not 1280*720.

Comment: Thanks. I had that, but edited it because I thought it was incorrect. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

How the webpage is displayed depends on your choice of brower and your settings. Chrome on my devices by default displays webpages by width in desktop mode, so I see the same content horizontally on my phone and Nexus 7. But I'd say the web browsing experience on Nexus 7 is much better than on a phone due to the large screen, you can definitely see more on the Nexus 7 (vertically).

Source: I have an original Note (larger screen than Nexus 4) and Nexus 7.

Comment: If you see the same content horizontally on both devices, then the only difference is the actual physical size. You're not getting more screen space on the Nexus 7.

Comment: I know webpage rendering depends on the browser and settings, etc. I was using it as an example to compare the same display content between the two devices.

Comment: How can you see more vertically when the pixel dimensions of the two devices are almost the same?